# Как правильно не дать заснуть Google cloud messaging на android?

Tags: android

По сути, проблема описана кем-то [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064337/android-programming-gcmintentservice-stuck-at-wakelock), но я совсем не понял ответа (было бы здорово, если бы вы помогли разобраться с ответом).

А остальные проблемы - что происходит, когда я блокирую устройство? По прошествии некоторого времени приложение перестает получать push сообщения от сервера, а когда включаю приложение, не начинает их получать заново. И при новом запуске старые сообщение также не доходят.

Comment: Разобрался - на некоторых телефонах приложению требуется еще дополнительное разрешение на фоновую работу - ставится в настройках или сразу после установки. Такое случилось, например, у меня на хуавэйе - все права запросил, walelock работал, но не действовало. В итоге нашел эту тему с настройками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно проверьте в AndroidManifest пакеты у разрешений и у *receiver*. Должно быть примерно так:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

 <permission android:name="<ИМЯПАКЕТА>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="<ИМЯПАКЕТА>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <application ...>
    <receiver
         android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
         android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <category android:name="<ИМЯПАКЕТА>" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
     <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
 </application>
```

По ссылке был неправильно прописан *name* у *GcmBroadcastReceiver* и сервис *GcmIntentService* был не в корне, а в каком-то другом вложенном пакете (должен быть обязательно в корне).

Answer (score 0):

Если судить по ответу из **stackoverflow**, ему отвечают, что нужно хранить весь `GCM` класс в основном package, т.е. где он вызывает `gcm registration`. Если я правильно понял, то ему нужно изменить `package com.mp2012.ieatishootipostanalyzer.notifications;` на `package com.mp2012.ieatishootipostanalyzer`.